# Probability 2 heads in a row in 3 coin flips given even heads

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with this problem. What is the probability that you get 2 heads in a row in 3 coin flips given that the number of heads will be even.

```
My Attempt:
Sample Space: {HHH, HHT, HTT, HTH, THH, TTH, THT, TTT}
Event F is even number of heads from 3 flips: {HHT, HTH, THH}
P(F)= 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 = 3/8
Event E is 2 heads in a row given F:
{HHT, THH}
P(EnF)= 1/8 + 1/8 = 2/8 = 1/4

Probability of E given F = P(EnF)/P(F)
(1/4) / (3/8)= 2/3
```

However the back of the book says that the probability of E given F = 1/2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 0 is an even number technically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TTT also counts as an outcome with an even number of H.